# How to modify a variable inside parent function?

Tags: php, class, variables

I want to modify $item of parent, then, let the parent run the rest process. How to do?
(I can't modify parent class which will be updated often by software updating. Also please note, $item is a variable inside function, it's not a parent->var)

```
Class Parent{
     function __constructor(){....}
     function save(){
       $items = get_items($id, $this->var);
       // process the data and save
     }
}
Class Child extends Parent{
     function __constructor(){
         parent::__construct();
     }
     function save(){
     $items = get_items($id, $var)// if.. then $var=$this->var, else $var=$something_else
      // precess data and save
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like bad design on the part of the third-party Parent class. Any solution is going to mean either code duplication or a hacky workaround, both of which present maintenance problems when upgrading. What package is this from?

Answer (score 0):

pass them as parameter. For example

```
Class Parent{
     function __constructor(){....}
     function save(){
     function save($items = null){
        $items = is_null($items) ? get_items($id, $var) : $items;
        // process the data and save
     }
}
Class Child extends Parent{
     function __constructor(){
         parent::__construct();
     }
     function save($items = null){
       $items = is_null($items) ? get_items($id, $var) : $items;
        // precess data and save
     }
     return parent::save($items);
}
```

Comment: I can't modify parent class, because it will be eareased when software upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Parent{
    protected $items;
     function __constructor(){....}
     function save(){
       $this->items = get_items($id, $this->var);
       // process the data and save
     }
}
Class Child extends Parent{
     function __constructor(){
         parent::__construct();
     }
     function save(){
         $this->items = something_else();
        parent::save();
    }
```

}

Comment: Depending on the design this may overwrite the changes saved in the childs methods.

Comment: $item is not a member var of parent, it's a var inside parent function. So, in child, $item might not be the recongnized as the same var